# Custom scoring function in Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a vector representation of each document as a field. Is it possible to run my custom scoring function against all these fields?

The scoring function takes a search query and document's vector and returns a number.

Answer (score 1):

Can you expand on the function you are trying to create? How are you trying to get a number out of a document vector and the query? Is the document vector an embedding describing the document? And do you wish to compare it to another vector of the same format describing the search query itself? If that's what you are trying to do, as of now, we have no built in support to score dense vectors. Your best bet would be to use supported/traditional method of scoring to return a large amount of documents from Azure Search, and then create a second ranker residing on your own server that will re-rank the results using your own custom algorithm (which could use dense vectors).

Comment: Yes, you understand the idea correctly, the document vector is an embedding describing the document. Is there a plan to add this functionality? I have millions of documents, so returning everything and re-ranking is not really doable in a reasonable amount of time. Sorl/Lucene already have an option to add a custom scorer

Comment: There's no plan to release this functionality in the near future, thought we are looking into it for medium/longer term. For the L2 ranker, you wouldn't have to return millions of documents. The way people usually implement L2 rankers is to first filter out documents using standard term based retrieval and ranking, and then do a second pass using their L2 ranker. For example, if you wish to return 100 documents ranked using vector proximity, you could return the top 1000 documents from Azure Search (ranked through TFIDF based algorithms), and re-rank them using your L2 to keep the top 100.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have learnt so far, cognitive search does not support custom scoring functions. You can translate your vector representation into an integer field and then apply the inbuilt magnitude function.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-scoring-profiles#functions